# Strange behavior of pandas DataFrame.agg

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

The Lambdas in the following code return the same Series, but the aggregation results are different. Why?

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame([1, 2])
print(df)
print(df.agg({0: lambda x: x.cumsum()}))
print(df.agg({0: lambda x: pd.Series([1, 3], name=0)}))
```

Which gives:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
   0
0  1
1  3
   0
   0  1
0  1  3
1  1  3
```

Comment: It seems a bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19756